# Can we set Kafka properties with apache camel, in spring XML configuration file

Tags: xml, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

Does XML configuration can access kafka properties in apache camel

```
There is no kafka and spring XML configuration is available anywhere
```

```html
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
   <from uri="direct:SpringXMLRouteStart" />
   <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
       <constant>GET</constant>
   </setHeader>
   <!-- To printout the routing message on the IDE console -->
   <to uri="http://localhost:8080/v1/get/WGS/inboundCMMessage1" />
  </route>
  <route>
   <from uri="http://localhost:8080/v1/get/WGS/inboundCMMessage1" />
   <to uri="kafka://localhost:9092?topic=customtopic&zookeeperHost=localhost:2181" />
  </route>
 </camelContext>
```

.....................My Error ...............

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "zookeeperHost" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using XML, you can't use '&' in route URIs like you would with the Java DSL so do:

```
&amp;zookeeperHost=localhost:2181
```